# Vim: open a temporary buffer displaying executable's output

Tags: vim, makefile

I have found the `:cwindow` command to be very useful and I was wondering if I could get similar functionality using the output of my compiled code. I'd the output of `:!./a.out` to appear in a "quickfix" style buffer.

I've also noticed that even after taking the standard steps to prevent the `"Press Enter to continue"` message, it still happens at least once on `:make` and `:!./a.out` - using `:silent` to suppress this causes my tmux to go completely blank. My current workaround involves a mapping with a lot of carriage returns, is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this:

```
" Shell ------------------------------------------------------------------- {{{

function! s:ExecuteInShell(command) " {{{
    let command = join(map(split(a:command), 'expand(v:val)'))
    let winnr = bufwinnr('^' . command . '$')
    silent! execute  winnr < 0 ? 'botright vnew ' . fnameescape(command) : winnr . 'wincmd w'
    setlocal buftype=nowrite bufhidden=wipe nobuflisted noswapfile nowrap nonumber
    echo 'Execute ' . command . '...'
    silent! execute 'silent %!'. command
    silent! redraw
    silent! execute 'au BufUnload <buffer> execute bufwinnr(' . bufnr('#') . ') . ''wincmd w'''
    silent! execute 'nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <LocalLeader>r :call <SID>ExecuteInShell(''' . command . ''')<CR>:AnsiEsc<CR>'
    silent! execute 'nnoremap <silent> <buffer> q :q<CR>'
    silent! execute 'AnsiEsc'
    echo 'Shell command ' . command . ' executed.'
endfunction " }}}
command! -complete=shellcmd -nargs=+ Shell call s:ExecuteInShell(<q-args>)
nnoremap <leader>! :Shell

" }}}
```

in steve losh's .vimrc - [see](https://github.com/sjl/dotfiles) which I shamelessly copied.

Answer (score 11):

Sure, you can use vim's preview window with a short function to execute the command, try this in your .vimrc:

```
fun! Runcmd(cmd)
    silent! exe "noautocmd botright pedit ".a:cmd
    noautocmd wincmd P
    set buftype=nofile
    exe "noautocmd r! ".a:cmd
    noautocmd wincmd p
endfun
com! -nargs=1 Runcmd :call Runcmd("<args>")
```

Then you can:

```
:Runcmd ls
```

And see the results of `ls` in your preview window

Comment: This causes vim to give me the colored "Press ENTER" prompt, even though i've taken steps to avoid that flavor of the prompt from appearing (setcmdheight=2). Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Hmm, that didn't happen for me in gvim however I've now tried it in vim and seen that issue.  Try the above, it fixes it for me.

Comment: that worked for that case, unfortunately i hadn't tested it on an actual executable - now I've dug up other issues. `code`:Runcmd ./a.out`code` will fill the preview screen with binary noise, and `code`:Runcmd a.out`code` will cause the "Press Enter" prompt again with simply "Shell returned X" being output

Comment: oops the formatting on that is really bad and i'm out of the edit window, sorry! here is the output of :Runcmd ./test in one of my D projects: http://pastebin.com/FcLCCcYs

Answer (score 0):

I have just discovered the `:read` command, which puts the output of a shell command into a window.

I went looking for this because I often want to grep for a file in the current directory which contains a certain string (and then open it into my current VIM).

Here is a shortcut I have in my `$MYVIMRC`:

```
noremap <leader>g :new<CR>:read ! grep -rn "
```

With this, when I press `\g` I get a new buffer created in a split window and find

```
:read ! grep -rn "
```

sitting waiting for me in the command area. Now I just type my search string, close the double quotes and hit `<Enter>` and the buffer fills with the command output.

Once done, a simple

```
:bw!
```

in that new buffer will kill it.

Comment: For this purpose, I've once found the following solution that puts the search results into QuickFix window and highlight matches for easy navigation. 3 lines in vimrc: 1) get window: `autocmd QuickFixCmdPost * nested cwindow 20 | redraw!` 2) actual command: `command! -nargs=+ Grep execute "let @/ = '<args>' | set hlsearch | silent grep -rI <args> ."` 3) mapping for convenient access: `noremap <leader>g :Grep<space>`

Answer (score 0):

First open a preview window, and set it to autoread a file:

```
:botr pedit +:setl\ autoread /tmp/out.log
```

Now just run your command, and send the output to the file.

```
:!date > /tmp/out.log 2>&1
```

The result of your command should appear in the preview window.

However, we are still getting the "Press ENTER" prompt.  A simple way to avoid that is to make a mapping that presses Enter for us:

```
:nmap <Leader>r :exec '!date > /tmp/out.log 2>&1'<CR><CR><CR>
```

I thought only two `<CR>`s would be needed but then found myself needing three.